# Upper bound for custom rand48

Tags: c++, random, cuda

I'm using a custom random number function rand48 in CUDA. The function does not allow an upperbound to be set, but I require the output to be between 0 and 1.

I guess I'm missing something but how would I convert the output to be between 0 and 1, the length of the number can change e.g. 697135872  would need to be divided by 100000000 and 29186668 would need to be divided by 100000000.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Does your PRNG return a constant distribution over some range? Do you want to return a `float`?

Comment: Its the same as a the standard rand(), and yeah a float would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PRNG behaves like `rand` then it generates numbers between 0 and `RAND_MAX` with uniform probability. You just have to multiply by `1.f/RAND_MAX`.

If you divide by different numbers in different cases, you will end up with non-uniform distribution.